# Strange ie behaviour with jquery inArray

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

Hello this seems to be working on IE8 :

```
var clsName = link.parents("div.fixed_column").attr("class").split(" ");

if($.inArray("column_one", clsName)
```

While this one reports error (Object expected errror in jquery).

```
var clsName = link.parents("div.fixed_column").attr("class");
```

What is the right way to do this? I thought purpose of inArray was that jquery will handle cross browser issues.

Comment: The "right" way to determine if an element has a class, is to use `$("element").hasClass("className");` - http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/

Comment: @Ian seems legit, I didn't know about that one. I've used this one so far I guess that answers my question if you would care to answer I'd be greatful and accept

Comment: what is the value for link

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is indirectly answering your question, but... You seem to be looking to detect if an element has a class, and since you're already using jQuery, just use the `hasClass` method - http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/

For your specific code, try:

```
if (link.parents("div.fixed_column").hasClass("column_one")) {
    // It has the "column_one" class
}
```

The more immediate answer to your question is that `link.parents("div.fixed_column").attr("class")` returns a single string. When the jQuery selector (`div.fixed_column`) returns multiple elements, which is very possible when using classes, using jQuery methods that get information (like `.attr`, using one parameter...to "get" the value) return the first matched element's value only.

So say the selector matches 3 elements:

```
["<div id='div30' class='fixed_column div30_class'></div>",
 "<div id='div2' class='fixed_column div2_class'></div>",
 "<div id='div17' class='fixed_column div17_class'></div>"]
```

Then the value returned from `.attr("class")` will be: `fixed_column div30_class` because it's the first matched element.

I'm not sure, but I think you're expecting jQuery to return an array of all the matched elements' values, which it just doesn't. So that doesn't mean jQuery isn't handling cross-browser issues, it just means you need to look up what the method does/returns.

I could've sworn that jQuery 2.0 has options for doing what you want - directly from calling the getters (or something similar), but I can't find it anymore :( Maybe I'm remembering incorrectly. Anyways, you could easily use `$.each` and/or `$.map` to look at every matched element, but it depends on what you were really trying to do with it.

Answer (score 1):

You can't read the attributes of multiple elements into an array with `.attr("class")`. But why don't you just target the desired class in the selector like this?

```
var cols = link.parents("div.fixed_column.column_one");
```

Then change your conditional to check for an empty set:

```
if(cols.length) { ...
```

Comment: "You can't read the attributes of multiple elements into an array with `.attr("class")`" - that doesn't matter...when you use any selector and multiple elements are returned, and then use the getter for `.attr`, it'll return the first matched element's class. Either way, I like your solution too

Comment: I said that because that's what the OP was trying to do, apparently.

Comment: Wow yeah, sorry...I think I misunderstood what the OP was trying to use that got an error with.